# Populate choices in a Django field (models) based on saved data

Tags: python, django

Let us consider the following model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    stock   = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    to_be_filled_later = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

suppose also that I manually created an entry with `stock` set to 42 and `to_be_filled_later` left blank.

When I go to the admin panel (modification) of `MyModel` and select my new entry, I would like to set `to_be_filled_later` to some value, but I also want to restrict the set of possible values **based on the current value of `self.stock`**, *i.e.* 42.

Since `Field.choices` can be set to any iterable, one would be tempted to do something like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    stock   = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def restricted_choices(self):
        # do something based on self.stock
        yield (some_stuff.pk, some_stuff.name)
    to_be_filled_later = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
                                          blank=True, 
                                          choices=restricted_choices(self))
```

however this won't work because `restricted_choices` should be called with a reference to `self` that is not defined in the scope where we create the fields (here in the definition of `to_be_filled_later`, to be precise).

We could maybe override `__init__` but that's not what we want since it would take effect just after every entry creation. What we want is to have a **dynamically, instance based** `choices`.

How would you go with this?

Comment: maybe django signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: why don't you do this in Form level? I kind of think pre-populate value should happen in the form.

Answer (score 2):

You *do* want to override `__init__`, but in the form, not in the model.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    to_be_filled_later = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['to_be_filled_later'].choices = restricted_choices(self.instance.stock)
```

and assign this form to the model admin for MyModel:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyModel
    form = MyModelForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```